# 1980s or 1990s art book about future of human evolution, not Man After Man

Tags: story-identification, books, evolution

I'm trying to identify an art book about possible future evolutions of humanity, all of which were heavily modified or adapted to a specific environment or condition. It is similar in concept to "Man After Man" by Dougal Dixon, but had a different art style and may have been published first. Unfortunately, that one has so far foiled all my attempts to track it down due to coming up as a false positive.

Another excluded partial match is that it was definitely too early to be "All Tomorrows" by Nemo Ramjet. Also I don't think it had any unifying plot or framing device - it was just a book of speculative art.

I'd have read it absolutely no later than 1994 and probably well before that. It was available in my East Coast USA public library system, so it can't have been completely obscure.

Imperfect memory says:

- It was formatted short and broad, with a form factor similar to a
  Time-Life book.
- Each variant got a two-page spread, showing the
  environment and the variant human.
- Variations were mostly
  biome-specific - an ocean-dwelling human variant, a plains-adapted
  human variant, and so on. There may have been a vacuum-adapted
  variant.
- It may have included a war-zone adapted human with a gas
  mask integrated into its face. This variant may have been shown in a
  quadrapedal posture.

Comment: Dougal Dixon has written a bunch of these speculative evolution books. https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dougal_Dixon

Comment: It is definitely not any of Dougal Dixon's works. The art style is wrong, and unlike Man After Man it doesn't use short stories or character voices as a framing device. Unlike his books that predate Man After Man, it's definitely focused on humanity rather than animals.

Comment: Have you tried calling the library?

Comment: This definitely sounds like Man After Man - 2 page spread (check), broad format (check), biome-specific adaptations (check), There's even a "far future post human" wearing a black space suit/mask (a bit Darth Vader-ish) riding another modified human.

Comment: @bob1 - yep. And yet the illustrations from Man After Man look nothing like what I remember. I also think it likely (though not certain) that I read this before Man After Man's 1990 publication. It's frustrating!